# CKFinder upload file url issue

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

I  have integrated **ckfinder** into the **ckeditor** for asp.net.

I have a issue that when I upload the file into the ckeditor but link generated and displayed like

```
/Folder/files/ruby_on_rails_tutorial_2nd_edition.pdf
```

but i want to display only file name as link like **ruby_on_rails_tutorial_2nd_edition.pdf**

How can I do this. Is there any ckeditor or ckfinder configuration required for generating the display name.

Comment: I see their some advance options but they just including the properties of the <a> tag but i have to just change the content of the tag like <a> ruby_rails.pdf </a>

Answer (score 0):

I would mark as [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253245), but the target doesn't have an accepted answer. This is copied form my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494732/694325).

You can just delete that text manually. If you mean you do it automatically using the Link dialog, this hack should work:

Replace "editor1" with your editor name in the hack below or hack into whatever system you have after the CKE js has loaded. What it does is listens to dialogs closing, when it sees that the link dialog is being hidden and that the current selection begins with an `<a...>` link, it takes the contents of said link and cuts it from the final slash.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

editor.on('dialogHide', function(e) {
    if(e.data.getName() === "link") {
        var sel = editor.getSelection();
        var se = sel.getStartElement();
        var text = se.getText();
        if(se.getName() === "a") {
            var newtext = text.slice(text.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            se.setText(newtext);
        }
    }     
});
```

It's complicated and disgusting but seems to work. ***Be warned, I have not tested this if it breaks anything else like anchoring. More checks would be better, like checking if newtext actually gets a value > 1 and only then replacing.***